# Qt QTableView::setRowHidden не прячет строку

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой (очень похоже на баг Qt), что при вызове метода setRowHidden строка не прячется...Притом происходит это именно в определённом контексте.

У меня есть программа, там есть таблица поставщиков, при нажатии на конкретного поставщика открывается окно с его информацией, в которой есть таблица с его поставляемыми товарами, которые фильтруются по категории товара. Так вот есть метод:

```
void SupplierWindow::RefreshGoodsTable() {
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    for (int i = 0; i < _goodModel->rowCount(); i++) {
        if (_goodModel->GoodAt(i)._category == _currentCategory) {
            ui->clothingInfo->setRowHidden(i, false);
            ui->clothingInfo->selectRow(i);
            qDebug() << "SHOW" << _goodModel->GoodAt(i)._name;
        }
        else {
            ui->clothingInfo->setRowHidden(i, true);
            qDebug() << "HIDE" << _goodModel->GoodAt(i)._name;
        }
    }
}
```

Который обновляет эту таблицу всякий раз, когда в комбобоксе меняется категория товара. Это работает на 100%, но не работает при открытии поставщика (то есть когда конструируется вот это вот окно), но если сменить индекс комбобокса, то всё начинает работать

Comment: я бы искал дурацкую ошибку (например, то что инициализация `_currentCategory` или присвоение модели виду происходит после вызова `RefreshGoodsTable()`)... если не видишь и считаешь, что это баг, то сделай [mcve], который его воспроизводит... ЗЫ: а вообще я бы вместо ручной фильтрации использовал бы `QSortFilterProxyModel`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, модель и категория инициализируются до, я в этом цикле выводил товары, там всё норм...Возможно, на более тонком уровне просто не успевает к этому моменту где-то инициализироваться внутри классов Qt :/
А с прокси моделью я пока до конца не разобрался, но смотрю уже в её сторону активно..